# how to see disk details from linux machine with which command?

Tags: linux

subject: LINUX - release.5.4- verify disk details from linux

with sfdisk -s I can see the disk capacity as the following:

```
    sfdisk -s
    /dev/cciss/c0d0: 143338560
    total: 143338560 blocks
```

but how to see also the disk details as disk manufacture ... etc

- I try the: , but I not get the right info -(:

  hdparm -i  /dev/cciss/c0d0

  /dev/cciss/c0d0:
    HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Answer (score 1):

SCSI : `sdparm /dev/sda` <sub><sup>([more info](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sdparm-linux-scsi-device-attribute.html))</sup></sub>

IDE/SATA : `hdparm -i /dev/hda` <sub><sup>([more info](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-getting-scsi-ide-harddisk-information/))</sup></sub>
also `hdparm -I` can work
(I found a bug report that stated that -i failed but -I worked)

Comment: see my last remark its not work -(:

Comment: @jennifer - Are you you sure it's a IDE/SATA disk?

Comment: @Jennifer - And I don't think hdparm works on RAID either.

Comment: I have SCSI sata ,

Comment: @jennifer - Then you should use sdparm and not hdparm